# Why isn't TZ normally listed in AcceptEnv in /etc/ssh/sshd_config

Tags: sshd

Why isn't the `TZ` environment variable normally listed in `AcceptEnv` in `/etc/ssh/sshd_config`? I'm not trying to solve a problem here, and I know that I can simply add it to the config file. What I'm wondering is if there's some reason it's not in there by default. I've looked at the distribution default files for OSX and a few Linux distributions, and they all have the same default: `AcceptEnv LANG LC_*`. Is there a reason `TZ` isn't in there too?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are [requests](https://bugzilla.redhat.com/show_bug.cgi?id=1349015) to accept and send this environment variable, but I don't see a point in doing that by default as I pointed out in the above bug:

> The LANG and LC_* are send/accepted by the ssh/sshd based on the report in a bug [#179851](https://bugzilla.redhat.com/show_bug.cgi?id=179851), 10 years ago. The arguments are mostly about the encoding, which might cause problems if not transferred to the remote session. But on the other hand requesting a language/locale/encoding that is not installed on the server causes problem in various tools unable to handle the errors.
>
> Both the above `LANG` and `LC_*` environment variables are standard in shell and set by default, unlike the `TZ`. Once you configure `TZ` in your local system (and you have got a reason to set this up to something different than system-wide value), you should be able to configure also the server with the same TZ or to send/accept this configuration. I don't think this should come by default.

So in short, this would cause much more confusion than help. Different users with different `TZ` settings would see different time formats and values on the same server for the same events.

Though, if you can present a good reason why it should go there, I am able to listen.

Comment: Thanks. I thought `TZ` was standardized and universal, but if it's not, that's reason enough to leave it out. Now that I've thought about it, I wouldn't want `TZ` overridden on my production systems anyway; it's more important to see what time the server thinks it is on those systems, because servers ought to be set to UTC all the time and apps ought to be tested with that setting. I'll just set it in my profile for my personal/desktop systems, which I use interactively and want to see local times on.

Answer (score 0):

I use a number of remote clusters with job-control systems like SLURM and PBS.
When I look at the start-times and expected finish-times on running jobs, it's convenient to see them in my local time.
I do travel a lot, so propagating the TZ variable from my laptop would make it very simple to deal with this.

I get that it would be a problem if the remote cluster didn't have a current list of timezones and couldn't recognize the one I'm sending.
But none of this will happen if I don't use an explicit SendEnv.
So if I see problems on one of the remote clusters, I'll either not send the TZ to that one, or try to find a more canonical setting (like GMT-relative or something).

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://superuser.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://superuser.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/late-answers/1208232)

Comment: Yeah, ok, I entered the info in the wrong pane.
But the posted answer is incorrect. If sending the TZ causes problems, don't send it.